# How to avoid Initialization of web user control inside aspx?

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page which contains a web user control as below.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <uc1:WebUserControl Visible="false" ID="WebUserControl1" runat="server" />
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="This is visible"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the Page_Load method of the above page I am setting the Visible = true/false (based on some condition) for the WebUserControl1. WebUserControl1 contains lots of control itself. But I don't want to initialize the controls inside WebUserControl1. Is there anyway we can avoid initializing the ChildControls of WebUserControl1?

Comment: How is it that _you_ know enough to not initialize the controls, but the developer of the user control does not? If the user control wants to initialize child controls, then it expects them to be initialized, and you'd better let it do that.

Comment: @John: WebUserControl1 is a very heavy control and I would rather not let it initialize if its not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you description, it sounds like the heavy lifting that is being done in the user control is done in the Init event of the user control. May I suggest moving the heavy lifting out of that event to, possibly, the Load event. Then, as @Brian pointed out, you should be able to check if the control is visible and start the heavy lifting if it is.

Code-Behind for your User Control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Visible)
    {
        //do heavy lifting here
    }
}
```

If you don't put some kind of conditions on whether or not you lift, you will always lift.

Comment: I am checking the Visible property in Page_Load. However if my control is not visible why should it still execute its life-cycle events.

Comment: Can you please post your control code as part of the original question? I'm doing a little too much guess-work, here. I think you're getting close to the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Controls will be added to the control tree and that can't be avoided unless you add controls dynamically (which can be a pain), but you have to handle the backend logic checking.  In your user control code, you need to check for Visible = true when you attempt to process server-side logic, and only process when true.